# How to add environment variables in config.json?

Tags: environment-variables, sequelize.js

I am working on a database migration project and it requires me to use sequelize. I initialized sequelize's CLI (using npx sequelize-cli init) that added the config.json file:

- config, contains config file, which tells CLI how to connect with database

The config.json file has this object:

```
  "production": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_production",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  }
```

But I don't want to save my password in a config.json file. I want to use an environmental variable instead. What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

First you have to create a .sequelizerc file in root. Then add the following code there.

```
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  'config': path.resolve('config', 'config.js'),
}
```

*Note: Change the path as per your project.*

Then you can rename the config.json file to config.js and add the below code there. (As in Tunde's answer.)

```
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
    development: {
        username: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_NAME,
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        dialect: process.env.DB_DRIVER
    },
    test: {
        username: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_NAME,
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        dialect: process.env.DB_DRIVER
    },
    production: {
        username: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_NAME,
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        dialect: process.env.DB_DRIVER
    }
};
```

Comment: Latest version of node (20.8.0) have native support to use .env file without any third party package (like dotenv). how we can use that with sequelize-cli command ?

Answer (score 1):

Rename the config.json to config.js, install dotenv and use the below code

```
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
    development: {
        username: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_NAME,
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        dialect: process.env.DB_DRIVER
    },
    test: {
        username: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_NAME,
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        dialect: process.env.DB_DRIVER
    },
    production: {
        username: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_NAME,
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        dialect: process.env.DB_DRIVER
    }
};
```